# Update foreground activity from background

Tags: android

I have `ListView`, populated by an SQLITE table, that is updated by bluetooth spp input through the use of a `Handler`. (A bluetooth barcode scanner performs a scan-and-increment function to modify lines in the table.)  I `startActivityForResult` on a `ListItemClick` to bring up a view with more detail and the ability to change the record information.  While the detail view is active, additional scans will continue to update the original table and ListView.

Is there a way to notify the active "detail" view that the background table has been changed (and thereby enabling the foreground activity to display new data)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could send Intents to the "detail" activity with extras signifying the new data.  In the activity, override [onNewIntent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent%28android.content.Intent%29) to intercept them.  You'll also need to specify the launchMode of your detail activity in the manifest as singleTop

Comment: I am able to start the intent a second time (at least the "onNewIntent" fires when it should) but the bundle seems to contain the old data.

Answer (score 0):

When you finish the launched activity use setresult, this will give control back to onactivityresult call back on previous activity from where it was launched.